# Проблема использования cursor.fetchone(). Ожидаю получить None, но получаю (None,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Обращаюсь к пустой ячейке в базе данных на sqlite на python 3.8.

```
def get_translated_item_db(language, param):
    connect = sqlite3.connect('db\\users.db')
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT \"{param}\" FROM languages WHERE language = \"{language}\"")
    one_result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(one_result) # (None,)
```

Почему не возвращается None без кортежа?

Comment: А почему вы ожидаете None? Ведь результат-то есть.

Comment: Ну и вообще, покажите таблицу и запрос

Comment: Зачем возвращать `param`, который и так имеем? :) Я бы поменял запрос на `cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM languages WHERE language = ?", [language])`, а вы уже сами, если нужно, вместо `*` укажите какие поля нужно вернуть из таблицы

Comment: fetchone() возвращает не ячейку, а строку из результата запроса. `(None,)` - это как раз строка результата с одним значением None.

Comment: insolor,
Во всех аналогичных примерах всегда возвращается None без кортежа: 
`
def is_admin(username: str) -> bool:
  with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""
      SELECT
        admin
      FROM
        users
      WHERE
        username = '%s'
    """ % username)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
  if result is None:
    # Пользователь не существует
    return False
`
Это просто пример из поисковика. И здесь сравнивается значение не из кортежа, здесь .fetchone() вернул значение None

Comment: Кажется вы не понимаете разницу между «нет ответа» и «ответ со значением NULL»

Comment: Если в таблице есть запись по такому условию и там в нужном вам поле значение `NULL`, то возвращается `(None,)`, а если нет подходящей записи, то возвращается просто `None`.

Comment: Alexey Ten, вы полагаете, что, если ячейка существует, но пустая, то вернется (None,), а если я обращаюсь к ячейке, которая еще не существует, то вернется None?

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо, теперь понял!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в таблице есть запись по такому условию и там в нужном вам поле значение `NULL`, то возвращается `(None,)`, а если нет подходящей записи, то возвращается просто `None`. –
CrazyElf (с)

Comment: Зачем пересылать чужие комментарии? Лучше попросите @CrazyElf самого оставить ответ.

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 Да я не против. Может мне лениво ответ оформлять )

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 рекомендую почитать обсуждение здесь: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10628/1365

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 см. также https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/1365 Тема переноса комментариев в ответы довольно старая, в целом более-менее согласились, что в этом нет какого-то криминала.

Comment: Ну если автор согласен, я ничего)